# Compatibility of Authlogic with http_basic_authenticate_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, http-authentication

my Rails 3.1 application uses authlogic. I just added [http_basic_authenticate_with](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) so I can restrict access to the entire site for running a private beta, and it seems to have broken authlogic:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "frodo", :password => "thering"
```

With the above code, when I try and login using Authlogic 3.0.3, the authentication fails without error, and redirects me to the user_sessions new action.

What's going on, I would like to use both!